# onOptionsItemSelected not called in fragment with setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, fragment, appcompatactivity

I searched all day through all similar question and answers, here in stackoverflow, but found no clue why it doesn't work

here some excerpts from my code

Fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Portfolio");
    updateGallery();
    return rootView;
}


    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

    public void updateGallery() {
    if (activeAlbum>0) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } else {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
 ......
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {...}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

....

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


......
 }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

onOptionsItemSelected is fired neither in MainActivity nor in Fragment

Answer (score 1):

Fragments have to declare that they can provide options. Have a look here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

I think you just need to call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the onCreateView() of your Fragment.

Comment: thank you for the link, I'll take a look 

(I'm already calling setHasOptionsMenu(true))

I fear something else could be interfering with onOptionsItemSelected
(maybe I should try to add a new "empty" fragment to test)